# Cell is not placed beside the Multicell

Tags: php, fpdf

I am creating a invoice in pdf format using fpdf in php. My requirements is to **create a comment box using multicell(),** and **beside of the comments, I want to show grand total of the bill using cell()**. But in the output the **cell is showing below of the multicell instead placed in beside of the multicell**.

My code is:

```
$pdf->SetFillColor(204,204,204);        //for filling grey color
$pdf->cell(105,5,'Comments',1,1,'',true);  //header of the comment box
$pdf->MultiCell(105,30,'abcd',1,'');     //content of the comment box
$pdf->cell(5,5,'Grand Total',1,1,'C');   //show grand total of the bill
```

Am I clear? If not comment it, I will describe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set your X-coordinate for the next cell like this:-

```
$current_y = $pdf->GetY();
$current_x = $pdf->GetX();
$pdf->MultiCell(105,5,'value',1,'T', false,'T');
$pdf->SetXY($current_x + 100, $current_y);
<next-cell>
```

And you get next cell just after MultiCell. Hope it will work for you...